# Word Spacing Makes Bottom Margin Too Big

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I want my bottom margin to be exactly one inch, but my double spacing settings adds a bit of space after the text on top of the 1" margin, extending the bottom margin too far. How can I prevent this?

Comment: It sounds like you may be referring to several different things.  The bottom margin is a reserved space that doesn't allow body content, but it doesn't affect where text ends above that.  Where text ends depends on how much text there is, whether you enable options like keep lines together or keep with next, how much text needs to go on the next page, where a new paragraph starts in relation to what wraps to the next page, etc.  The amount of space below the last line on a page will normally vary.  There isn't a layout setting that forces a fixed distance below the last line.

Comment: thanks for the help, i just found that disabling the "widow/orphan control" stops the issue of forcing the beginning of paragraphs to the next page, but i still have another issue with this all. I'll edit my question to reflect the exact problem i am having

Comment: The bottom margin can be set to exactly what you want.  It sounds like you're talking about the space between the bottom of the body text and the bottom of the page.  If the bottom margin is set to 1", there shouldn't be any body text below that.  In relation to where the body text ends, there's no single setting you can enable or disable to precisely control that.  If you want an exact measurement regardless of content, it will take manual adjustment.

Comment: Either I misunderstood you or I wasn't clear enough for you to understand my exact problem so I edited the issue to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: There are dozens of things that collectively determine where the body text ends on the page.  If you want to force the bottom of the text to be at a specific distance from the bottom of the page (or bottom margin), it will take manual fine tuning; spread the adjustment into micro changes in many places.  To adjust a big gap, make an imperceptible adjustment to all of the line spacing.  Then make an imperceptible adjustment to all of the paragraph spacing.  Look for places where you can reword or hyphenate to fit more text on specific lines to eliminate a short last line of a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word (unlike, I believe, TeX or LaTeX) won't do minute positive/negative adjustments to line spacing so that the area between the top and bottom margins is filled exactly, leaving a bottom margin of precisely 1".

The best you can do – and it can actually be very good, though it takes a bit of effort – is figure out how much vertical space each page has between the top and bottom margins (it's useful to change Word's unit of measure to points for this, in Word Options), and then set an *exact* line height value (in points) that divides evenly into that value – or as close to evenly as you can reasonably get. (Since it sounds as though you care more about the bottom margin than the top margin, you can increase or decrease the size of the top margin by a bit to make the amount of vertical space a figure that's easier to divide evenly into.)

Basically, this means that you're laying out your pages *in a grid*. If the line height/spacing for all other elements, such as headings, is in harmony with this vertical 'grid,' all pages will be completely filled top to bottom.

I do this quite often, in both Word and OpenOffice, and find the results well worth the extra bit of work.

---

**Update:** Here's an example.

If the paper size is US letter, the total page height is 11" = 792 pt.

If the top and bottom margins are 1" (= 72 pt) each, the height of the text area is 792 – (72 × 2) = 648 pt.

**If the font size is 11 pt**, double line space is (nominally) 22 pt.

See how many 22-pt lines will fit in the text area: 648 ÷ 22 = 29.45454545...

Remove the remainder, and find out how much space exactly 29 lines of text require: 22 × 29 = 638 pt.

Therefore, if you have 29 lines spaced at 22 pt, you'll have 10 pt of extra space to deal with (648 – 638; corresponding to the .45454545 remainder above). So increase the top margin by 10, to 82 pt.

**If the font size is 12 pt**, double space is (nominally) 24 pt.

See how many 24-pt lines will fit in the text area: 648 ÷ 24 = 27

In this case (or if you use 11-pt font with 24-pt line spacing), no further adjustment is needed. If you set the **Line spacing** property to **Exactly** at **24 pt**, exactly 27 lines of text will fit on each page.

For headings, and other elements, just make sure that the line spacing and any space above/below work within the 22-pt or 24-pt grid that you've established.